# How to count daily sales of salesman and show dates as a column in SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sales table like this

```
salesmanID  customerID  productID   date
        1          100          1   20.02.2015
        1          101          2   20.02.2015
        1          102          4   21.02.2015
        2          122          6   20.02.2015
        2          120          2   22.02.2015
        3          150          1   23.02.2015
        3          144          8   23.02.2015
        3          122          4   24.02.2015
```

and I want to count of daily sales for each salesman day by day between min and max dates of given two dates(in this sample 20-02-2015 and 24-02-2015) like this,

```
salesmanID  20.02.2015  21.02.2015  22.02.2015  23.02.2015  24.02.2015
         1          2            1           0           0           0
         2          1            0           1           0           0
         3          0            0           0           2           1
```

How can I do this in SQL query?

Comment: Do you do any research? Check for `PIVOT`

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language. Microsoft SQL Server (`sql-server`) is a completely different DBMS product. So what are you using?

Comment: If your columns are dynamic, you need to use dynamic SQL ;).

Comment: I will do this ms-sql, not plsql sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and `count of SalesmanID`

```
declare @temp table
(salesmanID int, customerID int, productID int,  dates VARCHAR(10))
        insert into @temp values (1,100,1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '20.02.2015', 104) )
        insert into @temp values (1,101,2,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '20.02.2015', 104) )
        insert into @temp values (1,102,4,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '21.02.2015', 104) )
        insert into @temp values (2,122,6,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '20.02.2015', 104) )
        insert into @temp values (2,120,2,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '22.02.2015', 104) )
        insert into @temp values (3,150,1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '23.02.2015', 104) )
        insert into @temp values (3,144,8,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '23.02.2015', 104) )
        insert into @temp values (3,122,4,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '24.02.2015', 104) )

--QUERY
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT salesmanID, salesmanID as id,dates 
        FROM @temp) as s
PIVOT
(
    count(id)
    FOR dates IN ([20.02.2015], [21.02.2015], [22.02.2015], [23.02.2015], [24.02.2015])
)AS pivots
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: @mesutkaya glad it helps you